# Changing button span via jQuery

Tags: magento-1.9, javascript, jquery

I have a slide that displays products in magento. Every time the user clicks on the `buy` button, I need the span of that button to change to `remove` and the other buttons to be `disabled` for the click and when the user clicks the `remove` button, the span of the button changes to `buy`. This should all be done using jQuery so that the page was not updated, but even researching I have no idea how I could do this.

**Button code:**

```
<button type="button" title="<?php echo Mage::helper('core')->quoteEscape($this->__('Add to Cart')) ?>" class="button btn-cart" onclick="addCartao('<?php echo $_product->getId(); ?>')" name="cartaoMensagem" id="cartaoMensagem"><span><span><?php echo $this->__('Add to Cart') ?></span></span></button>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**use this code to get span value of the button :**

```
    $("#cartaoMensagem").click(function(){
        $(this).find('span').find('span').html("Remove Cart"));
    });
```

Comment: I tested your code and it returns me the `alert` yes, however how could I manipulate it to be able to make the changes in the `span` according to the click of the user and what I described in the question?

Comment: You want to change same button text(span text) when click on add to cart button?

Comment: Yes, that's right.

Comment: Check updated answer sir....

Comment: Happy to helping sir :) .... Happy Coding !!!

Comment: You can give upvote if this answer is helpful ...